# How can i convert a array from firestore in a list to use in a dropdown menu in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm new to flutter and i want to fetch a array from firestore and then add all items to a List Schools variable.
I have structure in firebstore as follows:
ListOfSchool -> List -> An array with name of schools

So far i have tried this:

```
CollectionReference SchoolList = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ListSchools');

List<dynamic> Schools = [];

_fetchSchoolList() async{
DocumentSnapshot result = await SchoolList.doc('List').get().then((value) {
  Schools.add(value);
});
 
}
```

But this is giving me a error:

**The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a function which fetch datas from the firebase server, like this.

```dart
void fetchFirebaseData() async {
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  firestoreInstance.collection("ListSchools").doc('List').get().then((value) {
    //do something
  });
}
```

You mentioned that you want to use these datas in a dropdown menu/dropdown list. When you want to do something like this, you should use futurebuilder because fecthing datas takes some time. I believe this is why you get null value. By the way, this is why `fetchFirebaseData` function is an async function.

```dart
FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: fetchFirebaseData(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      List<String> schools = snapshot.data ?? new List<String>();
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? DropdownButton<String>(
                items: schools.map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: new Text(value),
                );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (_) {},
            ),
          : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }),
```

Comment: The FutureBuilder is giving error "A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<String>'."

Comment: My fetch function is: fetchSchoolList() async {
    DocumentSnapshot result = await SchoolList.doc('List').get();
    var data = result.get('List');
    List.from(data).forEach((element) {
      Schools.add(element);
    });
  }

Comment: where Schools is a list of type List<String> and i want this list as my dropdownformfield.